# Django urls keywords

Tags: python, django, url

With the following Django code, I have a problem when passing a url keyword to the template.

views.py

```
def index(request,username):
    return render(request,'myaccount.html')
```

urls.py from projectname folder

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^myaccount/',include('myaccount.urls')),
)
```

urls.py from myaccount app

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$','myaccount.views.index',name='myaccount'),
)
```

The question is, why when I use the following html code it shows **/myaccount/Jerry/**

```
myaccount.html

    {% url 'myaccount' 'Jerry' %}
```

but it shows **error** when I pass the keyword?

```
myaccount.html

    {% url 'myaccount' username %}

NoReverseMatch at /myaccount/Jerry/
Reverse for 'myaccount' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

The error gets fixed when I pass the variable username like that:

```
def index(request,username):
    return render(request,'myaccount.html',{'username':username})
```

But, is there a faster way?

Comment: Would you elaborate what you mean by faster way? Is this authenticated content or is username something else?

Comment: @PaulRenton It is about getting a var called 'username' in any url that includes `?P<username>`. It doesn't need to be logged in.

Comment: Okay let me know if my revised answer is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex you are capturing a key/value pair where the key is equal to username. You need to specify username='Jerry' in your url tag.

The P < username > means capture the following and link it to a keyword called username.

```
{% url 'myaccount' username='Jerry' %}
```

So in your case, if you don't provide a keyword argument for the Reverse look-up, it will look for a regex pattern that does not exist.

**EDIT**

This may address your 'faster way' concern. You should try using a Class Based View. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView

If one were to use the url pattern->

```
    url(r'^(?P<somenumber>\d+)/test/$', views.TestView.as_view(), name='testview')
```

Where TestView is defined in views.py as (Be sure to import views in your url.py)

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
class TestView(TemplateView):
    model = xxxx // link to your model here
    template_name = 'test.html'
```

In the test.html template you just have to do this

```
{{ somenumber }}
```

to extract the value of the passed in argument.

The get_context_data(self, **kwargs) function of the TemplateView will autmatically update the context of the template to include any key/value pair arguments found in your url pattern.

In fact, you can override this function and call super to update any custom k/w arguments you want in the template context.

Comment: I'd like this process automatic. Should I have to pass the variable username by doing `render(request,'.html',{'username':username}` then? Or is there are other faster way?

Comment: You could use a Class Based View and update the context ** kwargs with the username. If you define the username variable, this should prevent hardcoding of usernames.

Comment: Jerry, take a look at this link for CBV TemplateView https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView . The **kwargs consolidates passed in key/word arguments. You can use these to update the context for the template.

Comment: @Jerry, if you use username in many different templates, I think you can write a simple two-line context processor [like that](https://gist.github.com/strogonoff/5986120)

Comment: Another possibility is storing the username in a session and having a CBV inherit from a LoginSessionMixin which updates the context with session data, such as a username and other credentials.